# Why sorted list_b has no value?

Tags: python, list

I'm a total beginner. 
Please give me an explanation why `list_b` has no value for this simple code.

```
list_a = [3,2,1,4]
list_b = list_a.sort()
print(list_a,list_b)
```

I thought that list_b has a value of `list_a.sort()` which is `[3,2,1,4]` but it has `None` value. Please somebody help me to understand this.

Comment: Not this again: **`.sort()` sorts inplace**. It does **not return the sorted list**, it returns `None`.

Comment: as Willem said, `.sort` sorts the `list_a` and modifies it, it does not return a sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

```
list_b = sorted(list_a)
```

Or

```
list_a = [3,2,1,4]
print(list_a)
list_a.sort()
print(list_a)
```

> [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builds a new sorted list from an iterable,
>   leaving the original list unaffected.
>
> [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) sorts the list **in-place**, mutating the list indices,
>   it modifies the list in-place (and returns None to avoid confusion).
>   Usually it's less convenient than sorted() - but if you don't need the
>   original list, it's slightly more efficient.

See more details from [How to sort](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do that :

```
list_a = [3,2,1,4]
list_b = sorted(list_a)
print(list_a,list_b)
```

If you do

```
list_a = [3,2,1,4]
list_a.sort()
print(list_a)
```

You will understand that `list_a.sort()` affect the proper `list_a`